# Informix throw internal error when creating new transaction in existing one

Tags: java, informix

I have task which run in transaction

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout = 600)
public int run() {
...
}
```

and I have method which should run in new transaction:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateSelect(String id, String newStatus, String oldStatus) {
}
```

now when my task read just one record then it is ok. But when task read more then one record informix throw internal errror when selecting second record in new transaction. I should also mention that record is deleted when there is no error. In oracle this works OK but in informix this throw exception. I tried to comment creating new transaction or not delete record and then it works OK. But this is no solution for me.

My informix version:
informix version: 12.10.FC4

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?  A single connection in Informix can only have one transaction active.  You might want/need to use savepoints for the nested transaction, or you might be obliged to use a separate connection.  I don't know what is paying attention to the @ directives and what it does — what methods it calls.

Comment: hm I am java programer I have no idea how I can create or use savepoints. Error is: system or internal error

Comment: I'm an Informix programmer and not a Java programmer. I've no idea how Java manages its communications with the Informix database.  This gives us an almost complete disconnect on resolving this problem.